# IOS Swift- Navigate to Home screen without Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I use firebase for authentication. Once user logs in, i want move to home screen with Tab controller.

App Delegate Function

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    navToSignin()
    return true
}
func navToHome()
{
    print("navToHome")
    let customTab = CustomTabBar()
    window?.rootViewController = customTab
}
func navToSignin()
{
    let firstPage = SigninNewVC()
    window?.rootViewController = firstPage
}
```

SigninNewVC

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid != nil
    {
        if let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate  as? AppDelegate
        {
            print("viewWillAppear")

            appDel.navToHome()
      //This func gets called but still does not navigate to Home VC
        }
    }
}

private func fbSignin(token: String)
{
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCustomToken(token) { (user, error) in

        if error == nil
        {
            if user != nil
            {
                if let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
                {
                    JulehHUD.hideProgressHUD(self.view!)
                    appDel.jumpToHome()
                    //This part works fine when i login it navigates to Home Screen
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error:\n\(error)\n")
        }
    }
}
```

When i login for the first time it works fine I am able to Navigate to Home screen. But if i relaunch the App i not able to navigate to the home screen. It stays in the SigninNewVC though the print Statements print("viewWillAppear")& print("navToHome") are executed. Not sure what i am doing wrong. Below is my Tab bar class

class CustomTabBar: UITabBarController
{

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let homeController = HomeScreenVC()
    let newHomeTab = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
    newHomeTab.title = "Home"

    viewControllers = [newHomeTab]

}
}
```

Kindly let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you using xib or storyboard for the viewcontroller?

Comment: @Tj3n no i dont use it

Answer (score 0):

I think you insantiated the VC wrongly, you should be using something like `CustomTabBar(nibName: nil, bundle:nil)` and add your subview in it's `loadView:`

Comment: That dd not work. But i was able to fix it with adding below code to navToHome() & navToSignin() in App Delegate . Thank you anyways.
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: If it already work u should make your own answer and mark it resolved :D

Comment: sure i will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding below code to navToHome() & navToSignin() in App Delegate fixed the issue.

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)    
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```